# Downloaders email id when downloading free apps from play store

Tags: android, google-play

Can i get downloaders email id  when downloading free apps from play store?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.

However, with the user's permission, you could get the email IDs configured on the device. The primary account will be the one the user most probably used to download your app.

However, you should explicitly ask the user for permission to use the email ID, as it is a huge breach of privacy without permission.